# Laravel Eloquent query similar to findorfail

Tags: select, laravel, eloquent

I would like to look up and return an object referenced by a different column to that of `id`.

As far as I know there isn't another method similar to `Task::findOrFail($id)` but that can reference another field. For example:

`Task::findOrFail('column_name' = 'column_data');`

I'm currently using

`Task::where('tid' , '=', $tid)->first();`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe you can use the firstOrFail() function of Laravel.

```
Task::where('column_name', '=' ,'column_data')->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure that is what I wanted. (My edits didn't save so I was almost there). I was using the where clause and getting the first value `first()` but I didn't know that the '`OrFail`' existed.

Comment: Well, in my case it didn't work, however it did as `Task::where('column_name', '=' ,'column_data')->findOrFail($id);`